# Dynamic Pivot SQL table

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

Table `dbsize` loading with data of every database size every night.

```
dbsize (id, database_name, database_size, insert_date)
```

It looks like this:

```
 - 1   dbname1   1000   1/1/1900
 - 2   dbname2   2000   1/1/1900 
 - 3   dbname3   3000   1/1/1900 
 - 4   dbname1   1200   1/2/1900 
 - 5   dbname2   2200   1/2/1900
```

... etc

I need to get result like this

```
 - insert_date dbname1 dbname2 dbname3
 - 1/1/1900      1000      2000     3000
 - 1/2/1900      1200      2200
```

Tried with this sql, but nothing:

```
declare @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

select @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME(database_name) + ',' from  dbo.dbsize


set @ColumnNames = LEFT(@ColumnNames, LEN(@ColumnNames)-1) set @SQL = 
'select * from ( select     database_name   ,insert_date    ,id     from
dbo.dbsize) as BASEDATA

PIVOT   (

    count(id)   for database_name   in      ('

        +@ColumnNames + 

        ')  as PivotTable'


execute sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but nothing"?

Comment: I get some errors, I think that my code is not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close. Only a missing parenthesis at the very end of the dynamic sql string, the finishing parenthesis for the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx).

If you need to be able to handle multiple rows in dbsize with same database_name, you have to add a COUNT column and GROUP BY in your basedata query and change from COUNT(id) to SUM(count_column) in your PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames nvarchar(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ''

SELECT @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME( database_name) + ',' from (select distinct database_name from dbo.dbsize) t
SET @ColumnNames = LEFT(@ColumnNames, LEN(@ColumnNames)-1) 
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ( SELECT database_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM dbsize GROUP BY database_name) AS basedata
            PIVOT ( SUM(cnt) FOR database_name IN (' +@ColumnNames + ')) AS PivotTable'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08b4e/3)

Comment: Great, now it working, but now I get next error message:

The column 'database_name1' was specified multiple times for 'PivotTable'.

Comment: Your solution assumes unique values for database_name in table dbsize. The error message indicates there are multiple rows with database_name= 'database_name1'.

Comment: Updated the answer and the fiddle to handle multiple rows in dbsize with same database_name.

Comment: This is working. But, its not what I need. I need to get 1 row per date. That Row will contain every database_size.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(d.database_name) 
            FROM DataTable d
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT collect_date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select collect_date
                    , database_size
                    , database_name
                from DataTable
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(database_size)
                for database_name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Final Solution.